# String to Char* Without memory leaks

Tags: c#, c++, c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I had try many ways to convert a string into a Char* but always got 2 errors when I import my DLL to a C# project.
the main function of my C++ DLL is like this:

```
//Example
extern "C" __declspec (dllexport) void Conv(std::string str)
{
    FFileList file_list;

    char temp_path[1024];
    sprintf(temp_path,"%s*",arg_path);

    GetFindFileListWin(temp_path,".mrs",file_list);

}
```

So, I Need to convert "str" to a char* because `GetFindFileListWin` is like this:

```
GetFindFileListWin(char* path,char* ext,FFileList& pList);
```

and pass it to `arg_path`.

I tried to do this:

```
char* arg_path = new char[str.length()+1];
strcpy(arg_path, str.c_str());
sprintf(temp_path,"%s*",arg_path);
delete[] arg_path;
```

but when I run Conv() in my C# program It says **Windows has triggered a breakpoint in Program.exe.
This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in Program.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.** (Same happens if I use _strdup).
So, I tried in other way:

```
std::vector<char> Chr(str.size() + 1);
std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), Chr.begin());
char *arg_path = &Chr[0];
sprintf(temp_path,"%s*",arg_path);
```

And I got **Attempted to read or write protected memory** message

My C# program do this:

```
[DllImport("Mrs.dll")]
public static extern void Conv(string str);
public void Convert(TextBox Tx)
{
  Conv(Tx.Text);
}
```

Hope someone could help me to solve this error,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at this: [`std::string::c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str)

Comment: declare your c function such void Conv(const char* str) and use it

Comment: Do not use stl containers in dll api (different compilers create different binaries for that). I even don't think that you can use extern "C" for a method which accepts std::string, since string is no more "C". Do not expect C# to be able to pass .net String into Conv(const char*) without any marshalling. Last, but not least, .net has surely better tools and you can rewrite your GetFindFileListWin method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your p/invoke signature is

```
[DllImport("Mrs.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void Conv(string str);
```

then your C++ declaration will be simply

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void Conv(const char* str);
```

and you won't need any `std::string` at all.

.NET and p/invoke do not know anything about `std::string`.

Comment: I tried to use Marshaling before in other way and I fail, but actually this works very fine in combination with @suspectus answer.
Thank you very much, sir.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the asterisk in the sprintf statements could be causing the problem. sprintf would expect a length parameter for the asterisk in the format string.

```
sprintf(temp_path,"%s*",arg_path);
                     ^
```

Comment: Actually, you're thinking of `%*s`.  In the code shown, `*` is just a literal character that will be output with no special treatment.  (And as a result, it overruns the buffer in several of the code snippets shown in the question)

Answer (score 2):

string is c++ object.So in dll it will not work

What you should do as I mentioned above just to do such

```
extern "C" __declspec (dllexport) void Conv(const char* str)
{
   //do whatever
}
```